# Get user location in android

Tags: java, android

I am not able to get the location of the user in android studio. I have choosed Java as my backend language. I need an alternative way to get the location of the user instead of fusedlocation, but I am not able to implement it in my project. Please help me with the code that I should use in my project for getting the location.

My Backend Code -

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button getLocationBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getLocationBtn = findViewById(R.id.getLocationBTN);
        getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLocation();
            }
        });

    }

    private void getLocation() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to get location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with fused location but its not working in my case. I need the code which used other method to get the current location of user instead of fusedlocation.